# Special character not showing in html2pdf

Tags: html, pdf, symbols

I'm using html2pdf and trying to display in a pdf a checkmark, checkbox(checked), a tick mark...anything that resembles  check sigh.
I've tried all the codes I could find :
`&#9745;&#10004; &#10003;` but all I'm seeing is '`?`'

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr', true, 'UTF-8', 0);
```

Comment: In your attempts, did you also apply a font that actually contains a ✓ symbol? (This one is [`U+2713`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm), but the same goes for your variants.)

Comment: I'm using `$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');` ...hope it has those symbols

Answer (score 2):

There was a problem with the font not being able to show those symbols
What I've done is I've added 2 different fonts, Arial as default and dejavusans for symbols.

```
<style>span{font-family: dejavusans;}</style>

<span>&#9745;</span>

$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('arial');
$html2pdf->AddFont('dejavusans');
```

Comment: This is indeed what I was suspecting; but I hesitate to classify it as "a problem with the font". Unless `html2pdf`honorates a font stack, the font is not at fault here.